# How do I default Atom to open a specific file extension with syntax highlighting for a specific language?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, atom-editor

I would like to set Atom to open typescript files ending in .ts with the TypeScriptReact language syntax highlighting by default. Whats the best way to do this other than changing the extension to .tsx?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward. In Atom:

- Type cmd-shift-p to open the search dialog
- Type "Open your config" and hit enter
- Add a customFilesType section as a child to core

In the example below, I'm adding the .ts file extension to map into the syntax highlight for TypeScriptReact's .tsx default highlighting.

```
core:
   customFileTypes:
     "source.tsx": [
       "ts"
   ]
```